# Infering shapes from overlap with a shifting circle

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[A recent episode of Star Talk Radio](https://www.startalkradio.net/show/exploring-exoplanets-seth-shostak-startalk-stars/) discussed among other things the unknown object(s) orbiting [Tabby's star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIC_8462852) (aka "Alien mega structure discovered!" in non-scientific media) and an astronomer said with confidence that we know that whatever is orbiting that star isn't a planet because "it isn't round". Given that the mysterious object(s) were discovered by examining the variations in luminosity coming from the star, this got me thinking about light curves and what they can tell us about transiting objects.

Most generally my question is this:

> Given a closed subset $A\subseteq D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ where $D$ is the closed unit disc, what can we infer about the shape of $A$ when we are given the "light curve" $L_A(t)=\lambda^2(D\setminus (A+te_1))$ or equivalently if we are given $t\mapsto\lambda^2(D\cap (A+te_1))$.

In particular I would like to know:

> Can we distinguish convex sets from non-convex sets? And if yes, are convex $A$ uniquely determined by their $L_A$ (up to obvious non-uniquenesses like reflection across the x-axis)?

Doing some elementary geometry one finds that circles are indeed detected by their light curves thus validating Dr. Shostak's claim.

Comment: If there is any confusion, $\lambda^2$ is the Lebesgue measure on the plane.

Comment: Yet there are subsets $A$ of $D$ whose light curve is different to that of any convex object, so that the astronomer claim is plausible, after all (for instance, if $A$  has two connected components separated by the $y$-axis, its light curve would detect it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convex set and a non-convex set can have the same light curve.

Let $r$ be the reflection about the $x$-axis. Then $r(S)$ has the same light curve as $S$. So, let $C$ be a convex set above the x-axis, and let $C = C_1 \cup C_2$. Then $C$ has the same light curve as $C_1 \cup r(C_2)$.

Comment: If one positions $C$ on the $x$-axis not above, then one can even arrange it such that both $C_1 \sqcup C_2$ and $C_1 \sqcup r(C_2)$ are convex. Therefore light curves cannot distinguish between convex sets. Thanks!